# Ipv4 and IPv6 Calculating in binary

Tags: ipv6, ipv4

IPv4 would have a value of
?
in binary (show all 4 bits, even if they are 0s) and 0x
?
in hex (1 hex character).

IPv6 would have a value of
?
in binary (show all 4 bits, even if they are 0s) and 0x
?
in hex (1 hex character).

How would I calculate this?

Google is my best friend and I tried figuring out the right answer and at first I had 0100 and 4 as an answer for IPV4 and 0100 and 6 as an answer for the IPV6 but it came back as incorrect..

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `0100` in binary is not `6`. How do you think that `4` and `6` are both `0100` in binary?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

https://networking.grok.lsu.edu/Article.aspx?articleid=12692

Decimal     Binary

0           0000

1           0001

2           0010

3           0011

4           0100

5           0101

6           0110

Comment: Thank you so much! I am new to all of this which you could have probably guessed and I was so confused , now it’s all clear